# Populating Purchase order tables in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables `order_header` and `order_details` in mysql. The first table`order_header` contains `order_id`, `order_amount`, `order_date`. Shown as below :

```
    +----------+--------+------------+
    | order_id |amount  | order_date |
    +----------+--------+------------+
    |  2001    |  700   |01-02-2017  |
    |  2002    |  1200  |02-02-2017  |
    +----------+--------+------------+
```

And the second table `order_details` having  `order_id`,`item_name`,`quantity`,`amount`,`order_date`. Shown as below :

```
    +----------+---------------+---------+--------+------------+
    | order_id | item_name     |quantity |amount  | order_date |
    +----------+---------------+---------+--------+------------+
    |  2001    |Chocolate Cake |    2    |  500   |01-02-2017  |
    |  2001    |Bevarages      |    4    |  200   |01-02-2017  |
    |  2002    |Strawberry Cake|    2    |  600   |02-02-2017  |
    |  2002    |Bevarages      |    12   |  600   |02-02-2017  |
    +----------+---------------+---------+--------+------------+
```

My question is how to populate the data of `order_details` into `order_header` table when the `order_id` is unique in `order_header` table. And how can I generate the `order_id` in a sequence for a bunch of order in `order_details` table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below query may help you

```
insert into order_header(order_id, amount, order_date)
select order_id, sum(amount), order_date
from order_details
group by order_id, order_date
```